# How do SIP auto-corrections get communicated to a TextBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to debug a tricky situation with auto-correction not getting correctly handled in a TextBox, but I am stuck:
I cannot find how the tapping of an auto-correction suggestion in the SIP gets communicated to the TextBox.
I have traced the KeyUp, KeyDown, TextInput, TextInputStart and TextInputUpdate events, but they do not seem to be involved in the update of the Text in the TextBox object.

Background:

When a language other than Greek is used, auto-correction works as it should for a TextBox in my app. However, when the language is set to Greek, nothing happens when tapping on the suggested word ... On the other hand, in TextBoxes in standard phone apps (e.g. adding text in the Notes section of a contact) Greek auto-correction works perfectly. So, my first guess is that there is something wrong with the TextBox rather than with the SIP. My plan is to subclass TextBox, modifying only its auto-correction handling parts.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Gerasimos

**Update:**

I made a few tests and this seems to be a problem in all non standard apps. Specifically, I tested the eBay and SkyMap applications and in both cases English auto-corrections work, while Greek do not.

The problem is easy to reproduce:

- put a textbox in an application (with an inputScope that has auto-corrections enabled)
- use a Greek keyboard layout
- tap 1-2 random letters.
- tap on one of the proposed auto-corrections. Only the final space is introduced, and in cases that the cursor is between two spaces (as I preferred to test it) nothing happens.

So, I believe that there is a bug somewhere in the framework part and not in the application code. Now, if we could find how this auto-correction tapping is communicated to the TextBox... :-)

Comment: Does the `TextChanged` event fire?

Comment: @keyboardP No, the TextChanged event does not fire. The SelectionChanged event does not fire either...

Comment: @keyboardP If I tap on a Greek auto-correction then the text in the TextBox does not get updated and the TextChanged and SelectionChanged events do not fire. In the case of English auto-corrections, the text changes and these two events do get emitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to interrupt the SIP directly, You can edit the content of the textbox after the value has been entered/changed. Alternatively, you can implement something like an autosuggest if your intentions are to change the content instead of the visuals.

Comment: Apologies, I should have added more context: When a language other than Greek is used, auto-correction works as it should for a TextBox in my app. However, when the language is set to Greek, nothing happens when tapping on the suggested word ... On the other hand, in TextBoxes in standard phone apps (e.g. adding text in the Notes section of a contact) Greek auto-correction works perfectly. So, my first guess is that there is something wrong with the TextBox rather than with the SIP. My plan is to subclass TextBox, modifying only its auto-correction handling parts.